# How to set multiple session value to null in asp.net mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session

I have an Admin and User session.

```
 Session["uname"]  
 Session["Admin"]
```

My query is when session is over only admin redirect to login page. But when user session is over then it's not redirected to login page.

Please give me suggestion how to set session for both admin and user.

Here is my code

**User is my controller**

**Login Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(Models.User user)
{
        var query = db.Users.Where(q => q.UserName == user.UserName 
&& q.Password == user.Password);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //   Session["uname"] = true;
            if (query.Any())
            {            
                if (query.FirstOrDefault().Role.Role1.ToLower() == "admin")
                {
                    Session["admin"] = true;
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "user");
               }             
               else
               {
                    Session["uname"] = true;
                    return RedirectToAction("Details", "user", 
new { id = query.FirstOrDefault().Id });
               }
          }
     }

     return View(user);
}
```

And here is Index action

```
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
        var users = db.Users.ToList();

        if (Session["uname"] != null || Session["Admin"]==null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "User" );
        }
        else if (Session["admin"] != null)
        {
            return View(users.ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("About", "Home");
        }
    }
```

Thanks In advance.

After user's session is over it show something like this

```
Register | Sign In

Details
UserName
User
Password
User
Role1
User

Edit | Back to List
```

Comment: your code is not working???

Comment: @EhsanSajjad my code is working on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a session variable `Session["userType"]` whose values can either be "Admin" or "User" to determine what kind of user is trying to access your Index action method.

Have a look at [Authorize] attribute to control your access.

[MVC Authorize Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> > My Query is When Session is Over Only Admin Redirect to Login Page.But when User session is over Then It's Not Redirected to Login Page

In that case you need **AND** not **OR**:

```
if (Session["uname"] != null && Session["Admin"]==null)
{
     return RedirectToAction("Login", "User" );
}
```

or :

```
if (Session["uname"] != null)
{
        return RedirectToAction("About", "Home");
}
else if (Session["admin"] != null)
{
        return View(users.ToList());
}
else
{
       return RedirectToAction("Login", "User" );
}
```

Comment: what you mean by not working,, saying not working does not helps that what's issue

Answer (score 0):

i got a solution just small editing.

**Index Action**

```
Public ActionResult Index()
    {          
        var users = db.Users.ToList();
         var session = Session["uname"];
        if (Session["admin"] == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "User");
        }
        else if (Session["admin"] != null)
        {
            return View(users.ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("About", "Home");
        }
    }
```

And As I Redirected to **Detail Action**  I write Session Null code in Detail Action.

```
   public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        User user = db.Users.Find(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        if (Session["uname"] == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("About", "Home");
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

And Also Make Changes In **_Layout.cshtml** file

```
  @if (Session["uname"] == null && Session["admin"]==null)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Register", "create", "User")

    <span>| </span>

    <strong>@Html.Encode(User.Identity.Name)</strong>
    @Html.ActionLink("Sign In", "Login", "User")
}
else
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Sign Out", "Logout", "User")
}
```